# Why is my server displaying openssl 0.9.8 when I have openssl1.0.1 installed?

Tags: freebsd, openssl, apache-2.4

I am creating a test server that *is* vulnerable to the heartbleed bug.

My server is running Apache 2.4 on a FreeBSD VM.  By default, FreeBSD seems to have OpenSSL 0.9.8 installed by default.  I tried to uninstall OpenSSL from the ports, but since I didn't install it via ports( came by default ) I could not uninstall it that way.

Then I tried to just ignore it and installed OpenSSL 1.0.1 from source; but when I restarted the apache server, and checked the site using `curl --head 127.0.0.1` "OpenSSL 0.9.8" was displayed.

Then I tried to reinstall/reconfigure apache but the same test yielded "OpenSSL 0.9.8".

So, I tried to replace the default OpenSSL like so:
 - installed a newer OpenSSL via ports( in an attempt to replace the default version )
 - make uninstall-ed the port-installed OpenSSL( in an attempt to erase the default OpenSSL completely )
 - with my source-install the only one left, I figured that this had to have changed it
 - the test still yielded "OpenSSL 0.9.8"( sadness )

So, why is it still displaying "OpenSSL 0.9.8"?

I also want to change the website to use OpenSSL 1.0.1, so advice on that would be helpful.

Comment: OpenSSL 1.0.1 is open to the very severe heartbleed bug.  If you want to test against this bug, fine.  If not, consider using 1.0.1g or disabling heartbeats.

Comment: Yeah, I am specifically creating a test server that *IS* vulnerable to heartbleed-ing.

Comment: I would start by doing something like ```find / -name openssl``` and deleting any folders that are obviously linked to openssl.  You also may need to delete mod_ssl from Apache.  From there, I would compile the new version from source.

Comment: This post may be of some help too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1439950/whats-the-opposite-of-make-install-ie-how-do-you-uninstall-a-library-in-lin.

Comment: If you are planning to build a vulnerable FreeBSD test system, you should go for a base FreeBSD 10.0: OpenSSL 1.0.1e with the base system. Or have a look here: [superuser: about reinstalling openssl on FreeBSD](http://superuser.com/questions/742991/how-to-reinstall-an-intermediary-version-from-source).

Comment: Your `Apache` and `mod_ssl` were built against the *system* openssl (e.g. `/usr/include/openssl`). You will want to build against the *ports* OpenSSL.

Comment: The comments here are a bit misleading. FreeBSD, like most distros in the last week, released a fix for vulnerable versions of OpenSSL 1.0.1 (See https://www.freshports.org/security/openssl/ ). They also patched FreeBSD 10, see http://www.freebsd.org/security/advisories/FreeBSD-SA-14:06.openssl.asc

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The missing step is that you must say to the system that you want to use *OpenSSL* from ports over the one from the base system:

- build *OpenSSL* from ports:
- create/add to your `/etc/make.conf` the following line:

  ```
  WITH_OPENSSL_PORT=yes
  ```
- then **re-install** all the other modules needing *OpenSSL* (`devel/apr1`, `www/apache24`, ...)
- you can check the *OpenSSL* lib used by *apache24* (in fact the *apache24 mod_ssl* module):

  ```
  # ldd /usr/local/libexec/apache24/mod_ssl.so |grep ssl 
  /usr/local/libexec/apache24/mod_ssl.so:
          libssl.so.8 => /usr/local/lib/libssl.so.8 (0x801634000)
  ```

  The apache24 *mod_ssl* is now using the *OpenSSL* library from the ports.

Comment: It's actually "WITH_OPENSSL_PORT=yes". See https://www.freebsd.org/doc/en/books/handbook/openssl.html

Comment: Please note that "WITH_OPENSSL_PORT=yes" has been deprecated and that the "DEFAULT_VERSIONS+=ssl=openssl" mechanism should be used instead.

Answer (score 1):

Compiling OpenSSL will not help you much. Your Apache is still linked with the old OpenSSL. You can verify this using the `ldd` command.

You should recompile Apache or `mod_ssl` for it to be linked to your new OpenSSL.

Comment: by "recompile Apache" do you mean, go into the extracted folder, run ./configure [options];make;make test;make install?

Comment: @user2738698 Yes I do.

Comment: That is still not enough! `WITH_OpeNSSL_PORTS=yes` is needed in `/etc/make.conf`.

Comment: @Ouki is correct. On FreeBSD there can be be *two* OpenSSLs-- one included with the *base* system, and one (or more) included with Ports. Recompiling isn't enough.